# ¿Como puedo hacer que mis usuarios sepan mis nuevas actualizaciones (Retroalimentacion)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo una pagina donde subiré podcast, Vídeos y Articulos, Me gustaría saber como hacer que para cuando suba o mejor dicho comparta mis vídeos en la pagina web al inicio de la misma esta tenga las nuevas actualizaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Están compartidos por medio de youtube, ahora cuando yo comparta un nuevo vídeo a mis usaros, quiero que esa nueva actualización aparezca como un aviso en el inicio de mi sistema web para que ellos se dieran cuenta de las novedades sin tener que buscarlas.

Aquí esta mi pestaña de inicio, el rectángulo rosa es donde deberían aparecer las notificaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy usando ningún framework en particular y el lenguaje en el que estoy desarrollando el sistema web es php, javascript y html5 y un poco de jquery, por el momento no eh realizado código ya que no sabia como iniciar así que no me han salido errores, es una pregunta para la iniciación de mi código funcional

Comment: La información que solicitas es bastante amplia. deberías modificar la pregunta y centrarte en algo más concreto. deberías aportaa información acerca de que tipo de plataforma estás utilizado, (`wordpress`, `joomla`, etc) o si estás desarrollando tu propia plataforma, o... ¿usas algún framework? ¿has avanzado algo? ¿te genera errores? ¿te has informado de las distintas tecnologías para conseguir lo que buscas?. Si utilizas preguntas concretas, recibirás respuestas concretas. Si usas preguntas tan amplias probablemente se cierre la pregunta.

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo: 1- la manual o clasica, con las notif. en tu base de datos y escribiendo el html como resultado de una query a la base, 2- con websockets (o notificaciones push) (ej: http://socketo.me/) (esto consideralo un agregado a lo anterior), 3- usando rss desde tu canal de youtube, esta es quiza la mas simple de las tres, pues funciona sola, pero no tiene notificaciones, hay que emularlas. 4- long-pulling basado en http/1.1, prestaciones similares a web socket, requiere mas recursos server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar **Socket.IO**  http://socket.io/. Es muy sencillo, este ejemplo se conecta a twitter y emite un evento cada vez que encuentra un nuevo tweet de un usuario. Suena interesante implementarlo con el API de Youtube.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);
var cfg = require('./config.json');
var tw = require('node-tweet-stream')(cfg);
tw.track('socket.io');
tw.track('javascript');
tw.on('tweet', function(tweet){
  io.emit('tweet', tweet);
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: oye Felipe, socket io se maneja atravez de javascript? solo es curiosidad

Comment: Hola David, necesita dos componentes. Por un lado NodeJS y un cliente Javacript. Adicionalmente, Existe un componente de PHP llamada **Elephant.IO**  http://elephant.io/ pero nunca lo he utilizado.